# How can I efficiently list hyper-rectangle edges?

Tags: javascript, node.js

**TL;DR**

How can I efficienly list coordinates at the edge of an arbitrary hyperrectange?

**Description**

I have a function range that yields numbers in a range.

```js
export const range = function * (coeff) {
  let lower = -coeff
  let upper = coeff
  for (let ith = lower; ith <= upper; ++ith) {
    yield ith
  }
}

let result0 = Array.from(range(2))
// [-2, -1, 0, 1, 2]
```

I use `itertools.product` to list the cartesian product of these ranges (as an iterator)

```js
import * as itools from 'iter-tools'

let result1 = itools.product([ range(1), range(1) ])

[1, 1]
[1, 0]
[1, -1]

[0, 1]
[0, 0]
[0, -1]

[-1, 1]
[-1, 0]
[-1, -1]
```

I only want to select *edges*; arrays containing `coeff` or `-coeff` at least once

```js
const isEdge = (coeff, coords) => {
  return coords.some(coord => coord === coeff || --coeff)
}
isEdge(2, [2, 2]) // true
isEdge(4, [-4, 0]) // true
isEdge(4, [-3, 0]) // false
```

I'm listing all edges by running

```js
function * main () {
  for (let coord of itools.product([ range(10), range(10), range(10), range(10), range(10) ]) {
    if (isEdge(coord)) {
      yield coord
    }
  }
}
```

at the moment. This is an inefficient and round-about way of generating edges.

*Do you have a more efficient method of generating edges?* A reference to an algorithm would be helpful, or a short code-example.

It has to:

- be generator-based (like above)
- accept an arbitrary number of ranges (like `itools.product` does)

*Edit 1*

This program will still be bounded to O(n^5) when considering five-ranges, O(n^6) when working with six. However, the performance savings within that bound are relevant in this case

*Edit 2*
Bergi and John Trent, you are both amazing. I ran this program and generated around a billion edges as a test, and both the performance and heap-usage were really good.

The equation for edge-counting will also very helpful in setting up progress-bars, thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't start with all coordinates and filter them, generate only those that you need. This means that at least one dimension will have to be at the lower or upper boundary. While the  basic cartesian product works something like

```
function* cartesian(ranges) {
    if (ranges.length <= 0)
        yield [];
    else
        for (const x of range[0])
            for (const rest of cartesian(ranges.slice(1)))
                yield [x, ...rest]
}
```

we would now have to add a check whether we're already at a boundary or not, and if not then in the innermost iteration we'd only have to generate the two boundaries:

```
function* cartesian(ranges, atBound) {
    if (ranges.length <= 0)
        yield [];
    else if (ranges.length == 1 && !atBound)
        yield* [ranges[0].lower, ranges[0].upper]
    else 
        for (const x of ranges[0])
            for (const rest of cartesian(ranges.slice(1)), atBound || x == ranges[0].lower || x == ranges[0].upper)
                yield [x, ...rest]
}
```

Now an actual implementation (optimised to avoid too much cloning and spreading of arrays):

```js
function range(lower, upper) {
  return {
    lower,
    upper,
    *[Symbol.iterator]() {
      for (let i = lower; i <= upper; i++) yield i;
    },
  };
}
function cartesian(...ranges) {
  const coordinate = [];
  function* helper(dim, atBound) {
    if (dim >= ranges.length) {
      yield coordinate.slice();
      return;
    }
    const range = dim == ranges.length-1 && !atBound
      ? [ranges[0].lower, ranges[0].upper]
      : ranges[dim];
    for (const x of range) {
      coordinate[dim] = x;
      yield* helper(dim+1, atBound || x == range.lower || x == range.upper)
    }
  }
  return helper(0, false);
}

console.log(Array.from(cartesian(range(-3, 0), range(0, 3))));
```

Comment: Nice!  Just ran your algorithm with `range(-10,10)` with a dimension of 5, and came up with the expected result of 1,608,002 edges!  Your answer is definitely worth studying.

Answer (score 1):

Hmmmm... Interesting problem. So in the example...

- `itools.product([ range(10), range(10), range(10), range(10), range(10) ])`

...each range of [-10, -9, ..., 0, ..., 9, 10] contains 21 values, and therefore the total number of combinations is...

- 21 * 21 * 21 * 21 * 21 = 4,084,101 combinations

If the logic is to find any combination that includes -10 or 10, then I believe the total edges can be calculated as follows.  Take the first range and simply make it [-10, 10] and then iterate over every combination of the remaining ranges.  This will result in an edge count of...

- Step 1:  2 * 21 * 21 * 21 * 21 = 388962 edges

...and then take the next range and simply make it [-10, 10] but limit the first range to [-9, -8, ..., 0, ..., 8, 9] because we've already covered all instances of the first range where the values are [-10, 10].  This second step then contains an edge count of...

- Step 2: 19 * 2 * 21 * 21 * 21 = 351918 edges

...and continuing this logic through the remaining ranges...

- Step 3: 19 * 19 * 2 * 21 * 21 = 318402 edges
- Step 4: 19 * 19 * 19 * 2 * 21 = 288078 edges
- Step 5: 19 * 19 * 19 * 19 * 2 = 260642 edges

...for a total edge count of...

- 1,608,002 edges.

This edge count represents 39.4% (!) of the total combinations ( 1,608,002 / 4,084,101 ).

That being the case, in this example, you might be able to cut the time by a little more than half if creating a combination generator that follows the logic in Steps 1 - 5, guaranteeing that every result is an edge.  But this added algorithmic complexity might not be worth the effort if performance is not an issue when scanning all combinations.  Ie, you won't be saving *magnitudes* of checks compared to simply scanning all combinations.

I believe that the smaller that `coeff` is, the higher the percentage of edges relative to all combinations.  In fact, the example of `itools.product([ range(1), range(1) ])` has a 89% edge ratio.

So unless taking on very large `coeff`, am not sure introducing the complexity of generating only the edges is worth the effort.  Something to think about and assess, though, given the expected ranges and dimensions you anticipate...

**EDIT: A brute force confirmation of edge count**

The following code is a brute force means of driving out all edge combinations.  Note that given a range of 10 with 5 dimensions, the algorithm essentially treats the combinations as a base 21 problem, so instead of a range of (-10, 10), the algorithm assumes a range of (0, 20) and looks for cases where a digit is either 0 or 20.

**NOTE: This will take a few seconds to run!**

```js
function enumerateBruteForce( range, dimensions ) {

  let totalRange = BigInt( range * 2 + 1 );
  let max = totalRange ** BigInt( dimensions );
  
  let result = [];
  let leftover = [];
  for (let i = 0n; i < max; i++ ) {
    let digits = '|';
    let residual = i;
    for (let d = 0; d < dimensions; d++) {
      digits = '|' + residual % totalRange + digits;
      residual /= totalRange;
    }
    if ( 0 <= digits.indexOf( '|0|' ) || 0 <= digits.indexOf( '|' + ( range * 2 ) + '|' ) ) {
      result.push( digits );
    } else {
      leftover.push( digits );
    } 
  }

  return {result: result, leftover: leftover};
}

x = enumerateBruteForce( 10, 5 );
console.log( [ 'Combinations with Edges: ' + x.result.length, 'Combinations without Edges: ' + x.leftover.length, 'Total Combinations: ' + ( x.result.length + x.leftover.length ) ] );
```

The result will be 1,608,002 edges.  Note though that this is definitely not the optimal way of calculating the edges, but rather, simply a means of confirming that the steps described above will produce the correct result.

Additionally, as noted in the comments, all combinations ( 21 ^ 5 ) less all combinations that do not have an edge ( 19 ^ 5 ) also arrives at a count of 1,608,002 edges.

Comment: You are right to point out the combinatorial problems with this program, but they're by design! I'm trying to enumerate billions (done) to trillions (wip) of polynomial coefficients, then solve them to make pretty pictures. I think your edge-counting works but ignores cases with *multiple edges* at once. And you're right the Big-O complexity will be the same, but I need those constant-time savings!

https://github.com/rgrannell1/poly2020

Comment: The sample picture in your repo is reminiscent of a Mandelbrot!  Am editing my post to include a brute force algorithm that returns all combinations with an edge, and given the case of a range of 10 with 5 dimensions, I'm coming up with 1,608,002 edges, so am fairly confident that the steps described produce the desired result.  Another way of looking at it is that 21 ^ 5 (all combinations ) less 19 ^ 5 ( all combinations without an edge ) is 4,084,101 - 2,476,099 = 1,608,002.

Comment: Ignore my comment abount multiple edges, I believe your calculations are correct. Thank you for your help and your interest in this problem!

Comment: exactly! To be exact the images are of fifth-order polynomials solved with the coefficients in your code above. The more solutions, the better the picture. Currently I'm at ~10 billion 10k x 10x images, but this will enumeration approach will help me add storage and reach 1 trillion